# Could not build Titanium Android application to test in emulator

Tags: android, titanium

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (x64) with java 6 (as titanium requires), and as title says I cannot build Android application to test it on emulator. I keep getting this error

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/home/irmantas/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2206, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "/home/irmantas/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2037, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     launched, launch_failed = self.package_and_deploy()
[ERROR]   File "/home/irmantas/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1569, in package_and_deploy
[ERROR]     self.keystore_alias])
[ERROR]   File "/home/irmantas/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/2.1.0.GA/android/run.py", line 36, in run
[ERROR]     process = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
[ERROR]     errread, errwrite)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
[ERROR]     raise child_exception
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it turned out to be a java problem. The "No such file or directory" turned out to be jarsigner. To remedy the problem, borrowing from this information https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7 I entered the following

```
sudo update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/bin/jarsigner jarsigner /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/jarsigner 100 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jarsigner.1 jarsigner.1 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/man/man1/jarsigner.1
```

This fixed the problem immediately

Comment: Yes it was Java issue, just changed version to 1.7 and everything works. Thanks, and sorry for late accept :/

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions for you :

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/86751/android-emulater-wont-launch-adbexe-doesnt-start 
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121286/error-running-projects-in-android-emulator 
...appcelerator.com/question/120519/emulator-is-crashing-unexpectedly

1. Check that adb is accessible in tools and platform-tools folders
2. Check that there are no funny encodings in your app.js
3. Use the android tool to resave or delete the Titanium AVD

For

java -version

you should get

java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode, sharing)